# SQL Server Join on Select statement using count() and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables in SQL Server, `tbl_disputes` and `tbl_disputetypes`. The `tbl_disputes` table contains a foreign key column `disputetype`. The table `tbl_disputetypes` contains the primary key field `disputetypeid` and `disputetypedesc`. The following query gives me a count of each `disputetype` from the `tbl_disputes` table.

```
select disputetype, count(disputetype) as numberof
from tbl_disputes
group by disputetype
```

What sort of join or subquery do I need to use to display the 
`tbl_disputetypes.dbo.disputetypedesc` instead of `tbl_disputes.dbo.disputetype?`

**EDIT** Issue was because disputetypedesc was set as TEXT. I changed it to nvarchar, and the following query worked:

```
SELECT
    tbl_disputetypes.disputetypedesc,
    count(tbl_disputetypes.disputetypedesc)
FROM
    tbl_disputes Left OUTER JOIN
    tbl_disputetypes ON tbl_disputes.disputetype = tbl_disputetypes.disputetypeid
group by tbl_disputetypes.disputetypedesc
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: SQL Server 2005. The issue was actually due to the field tbl_disputetypes.disputetypedesc being "text". I changed the field to nvarchar and it works perfectly. I was getting the error: Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: I ended up using the query I had been trying all along, but I'm sure some of the others below will work just as well. Here is my query:
SELECT     tbl_disputetypes.disputetypedesc, count(tbl_disputetypes.disputetypedesc)
FROM         tbl_disputes Left OUTER JOIN
                      tbl_disputetypes ON tbl_disputes.disputetype = tbl_disputetypes.disputetypeid
group by tbl_disputetypes.disputetypedesc

Comment: How were we supposed to know there was an error message? You didn't tell us that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you can just `LEFT JOIN` the description:

```
select disputetypedesc, count(disputetype) as numberof
from tbl_disputes d
LEFT JOIN tbl_disputetypes dt
    ON dt.disputetypeid = d.disputetype
group by disputetypedesc
```

Comment: I like aggregating the counts first using the ints, then joining against the aggregate, instead of trying to group by the strings. Who knows how long those disputetypedesc values might be...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 2005+:

```
WITH x(t, numberof) AS 
(
  SELECT disputetype, COUNT(*) 
    FROM tbl_disputes 
    GROUP BY disputetype
)
SELECT dt.disputetypedesc, x.numberof
  FROM tbl_disputetypes AS dt
  INNER JOIN x ON dt.disputetype = x.t;
```

Comment: +1 - You could probably also use a Cross Apply for the underused function bifecta

Answer (score 2):

A simple JOIN?

```
select
    DT.disputetypedesc, count(*) as numberof
from 
    tbl_disputes D
    JOIN
    tbl_disputetypes DT ON D.disputetype = DT.disputetype
group by
    DT.disputetypedesc
```

Comment: As long as the `disputetypedesc` is also unique. Which I can't imagine it not being, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: +1 - I pulled a `LEFT JOIN` just in case a description field isn't populated.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that you will need a sub-query. Something like this will work:

```
select disputetypedesc, disputetype, numberof
from (select disputetype, count(disputetype) numberof
      from tbl_disputes
      group by disputetype) t left outer join
     tbl_disputetypes on t.disputetype = tbl_disputetypes.disputetype
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question however you should be able to select all columns using a query similar to the code sample below.

The following query will join the two tables by the disputetypeid column. I changed the format of the SQL statement however you can obviously format it however you would like.

```
    SELECT tbl_disputetypes.disputetypedesc
         , tbl_disputes.*
         , <any_column_from_either_table>
      FROM tbl_disputes
INNER JOIN tbl_disputetypes
        ON tbl_disputes.disputetypeid = tbl_disputetypes.disputetypeid
```

Comment: The OP needs to do a count, so your use of * and "<any column...>" don't make sense in this context. You will need to add a `GROUP BY` in order to obtain a count; how will you group by *?

Comment: Based on the question, it appears as though the question is more on the joining of the tables and the functions are not relevant. Thus I provided information on joining the tables based on my understanding of the question.